# Can't see gradient when using prefixfree.js

Tags: javascript, html, css

**EDIT** this helped

http://lea.verou.me/2012/07/important-prefix-free-update/

im trying to use prefixfree.js to shortcut around adding prefixes I think I'm doing it right but it's not working. I see in firebug that the script is loaded. No gradient is being shown.

html:

```
<body>
    <div id = "linear" class="box">linear</div>

</body>
```

css:

```
    #linear{
        background-image: linear-gradient(top left, red, white, green);
    }
```

I see a gradient when I use

```
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, red, white, green);
```

I thought the point of the js file was so I didn't have to put the prefix in.
Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use the latest syntax:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to top left, red, white, green);
```

it should works without prefix :)

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient