# Why gradient is not working in mozilla? It works fine is chrome

Tags: html, css, mozilla

I tried  -moz-linear-gradient in #inner , it is not working in Mozilla.

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient( 
    left top, 
    right top, 
    color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)),        
    color-stop(50%,rgba(255,255,255,0.01)), 
    color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8e45ocb7/

Comment: You also need to set standard way for that: linear-gradient()...

Comment: I would check out http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: Maybe a duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587799/cant-see-gradient-when-using-prefixfree-js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla gradients don't use `color-stop`, and only takes a single first parameter to define the directionality of the gradient.

The following definition [works for modern Mozilla browsers](http://jsfiddle.net/8e45ocb7/4/):

```
background: linear-gradient(
    to right,
    rgba(255,255,255,1),
    rgba(255,255,255,0.01),
    rgba(255,255,255,1)
);
```

And this one should work (untested) for older Mozilla browsers:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(
    left,
    rgba(255,255,255,1),
    rgba(255,255,255,0.01),
    rgba(255,255,255,1)
);
```

By the way, you should use `background-image` instead of `background` to avoid wiping out other things, and the `-moz-` prefix is only necessary if you're supporting moderately old (15+ versions ago) Firefox versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try following:

```
background-color: #49afcd;
background-image: linear-gradient(to left top, #5bc0de, #2f96b4);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

it works fine

Comment: missing the link to mozilla website for some explanations :) (duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25587799/cant-see-gradient-when-using-prefixfree-js )